/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist. Dropping to shell
I inherited a problem... originally we thought the root partition of the drive was filled and no one could log into the host.  The host was rebooted and upon reboot it now drops to initramfs.  I booted into a Live CD to try and vgchange but get an error:
Device has a size of 1442389101 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 163571712 sectors.  Was device resized?
No one has resized this device.  I can't mount the device because of the error.  I had been reading on similar problems for quite some time but I can't see to find an answer that works for me.  I can't vgchange, I can't mount... there's no room to extend the partition.  Can someone help me understand how can I make sizes match?
Thankyou.
